# Java threads scheduling

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a MainClass, a Worker class and a Supervisor class. In MainClass i create 10 Worker classes and a Supervisor class that run in separate threads.

```
class MainClass {

   public static void main(String args[]) {

   for (int i=0; i<10 ;i++) {
      Thread t = new Thread( new Worker());
      t.start();
   }

   (new Thread(new Supervisor()).start();

}
```

.

```
class Worker extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    while(true) {
      if(some_condition) {
        //do stuff
      } else {
        // pause thread execution for undefined time.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

.

```
class Supervisor extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    while(true) {
      if(some_condition) {
        // restart Workers thread that are paused.
      } 
      // do other stuff
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know how to implement this, cause the conditions in every thread are independent from each other so i don't need to synchronize, so i can't use wait-notify.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Did you look @ the classes available in `java.util.concurrent` ?

Comment: [these examples](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/07/java-thread-example.html) may help

Comment: Maybe, instead of `some_condition`, you can use either some implementation of `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` or N `BlockingQueue`, one per worker, which are feeded by supervisor, in correspondence, with either new `Runnable` or new data to process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know how to implement this, cause the conditions in every thread are independent from each other so i don't need to synchronize, so i can't use wait-notify.

Sure you can.

The subtlety here is that presumably `Supervisor` doesn't actually know whether worker threads are really paused. (If it does, then the conditions are **not** independent.)

Since Supervisor doesn't know whether the threads are actually paused (by assumption), you have to design what you want to happen if it tries to unpause an already-unpaused thread.

a) Should an unpause do nothing?

b) Or should it immediately unpause the next time a worker tries to pause itself?

If the answer is (b), then you have to worry about thread safety. If the answer is (a), then you don't (**unless you have some other data to pass between threads!**)

Either way, you can still use wait and notify.

Comment: If thread is un-paused than do nothing. The problem is that i don't understand how to use wait notify here ( i'm a beginner). A Worker waits if a condition happens but the Supervisor restarts the paused workers if an internal condition happens, that has nothing to do with the condition the worker paused. So, on which lock do I synchronize wait() and notify() ?

Comment: This is a very strange situation, but OK, assuming that's true, it doesn't matter. Just synchronize on a single global object. And call wait and notify on that object.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding u want to create separate thread pools which consist of 10 workers or number as per your requirement.

As far as pools are concerned you can check for `ThreadPoolExecutor`  in `java.util.concurrent` api.  Internally `ThreadPoolexecutor` also creates worker Threads for running tasks.

Try reading `ThreadPoolExecutor` it might help you or please elaborate your question whats your ultimate objective you wish to achieve by this problem.